# Laravel 4.2 InvalidArgumentException View not found

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, view

I can't get my Laravel app to load any views. I keep getting this error:

```
InvalidArgumentException
View [index] not found.
```

I am sure that the view exists, and It's just view loading, so I have no idea what could go wrong.

This is the controller method's code:

```
public function getIndex()
{
    // Get all the blog posts
    $posts = $this->post->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->paginate(10);

    // Show the page
    return View::make('site/blog/index', compact('posts'));
}
```

Comment: Post the code that is returning the view and also the location of the view file.

Comment: Please post your directory structure and also the value of `paths` in `app/config/view.php`

Comment: lukasgeiter you're a star! Your comment helped me find the problem. I had copied the app/config/view.php to app/config/development/view.php and that messed up the views paths. I changed the paths value from `/../views` to `/../../views` and it works now. Would you please post an answer, so I can accept it?

Comment: @ТомицаКораћ Glad I could help. Writing an answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel searches for views in the directory (or directories) that is configured in the view.php config file. (Default location: `app/config/view.php`)

**Attention:** The default value uses the `__DIR__` variable to specify a *relative* path. So when you move the file or copy it for an environmental config directory (in the OP's case 'development') you have the change the path accordingly.